# How to get my data back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm new to dynamic data and trying to

1. read data from a mysql database using PHP
2. turning this data to JSON
3. fetching the data through javascript (jQuery)
4. Inserting it into my page.

As far as I can see, 1) and 2) work fine, 3) seems to kind of work and 4) is where it breaks.

I've set up the database and the table, query & echo the data like so (api.php)

```
<?php 

  include 'db.php';
  $con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$databaseName);

  /* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}

  $query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
  $myArray = array();

  if ($result = $con->query($query)) {
    $tempArray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
      $tempArray = $row;
      array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
  }

  $result->close();
  $con->close();

?>
```

Now I get it through javascript...

```
jQuery(function($) {    
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'php/api.php',
        data: "json",
        dataType: "",    
        success: function(data) {
            var r = new Array(), j = -1;
            for (var key=0, size=data.length; key<size; key++){
                r[++j] ="<tr><td>";
                r[++j] = data[key][0];
                r[++j] = "</td><td>";
                r[++j] = data[key][1];
                r[++j] = "</td><td>";
                r[++j] = data[key][2];
                r[++j] = "</td></tr>";
            }
            var joined = r.join('');
            console.log(joined);
            $('#maintable tbody').html(joined);    
        }
    });
});
```

... and throw it in the tbody element of my table.

The result is absolutely not what I expected:

See https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9RZP.jpg (sorry for the partly german interface)

The Answer to the GET request is valid JSON, at least in theory (checked by http://jsonlint.com/ ), but to me it seems the data is treated as a string and split into an array of chars (each char a "key" in data[]), therefore "data[key][1] returns nothing.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + data + ")"));
```

and continuing with json[key][0] didn't help...

Now I wonder why and especially, **what went wrong and how its fixed**.

Comment: Why do you use the variable `j`?  You should use `key`.  This isn't part of an answer, but it seems unnecessary to have the two variables.

Comment: I think you have the options a little confused, passing just "json" as data, and a blank dataType ?

Comment: Why in the world are you doing `JSON.stringify(eval("(" + data + ")"))` at all? Was `data` not enough?

Comment: try using 'getJSON' or set dataType:'json' instead blank

Comment: Agree with EricSonaron. If you aren't using `$.ajax`'s specific fields, you're usually better of with `$.post`, `$.get` or `$.getJSON`.

Comment: Also, a more understandable way to use the variables would be: `for (var key=0, size=data.length; key<size; key++){
                r[++j] ="<tr><td>";
                r[++j] = data[key].key;
                r[++j] = "</td><td>";
                r[++j] = data[key].found;
                r[++j] = "</td><td>";
                r[++j] = data[key].comments;
                r[++j] = "</td></tr>";
            }` You can access the JSO by key name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mixed up the keys in your ajax call:

```
    data: "json",
    dataType: "",
```

Should be:

```
    dataType: "json",
```

as you are not sending or using any data at all.

Comment: Actually it seems jQuery guesses or something, I DO get the data. I "stole" most of the code from various websites explaining the procedure, so I have a hard time explaining how those weird things ended up there.  Same goes for JSON.stringify(eval...) (maybe some kind of injection protection?) and why I use "j" together with "key". Back to the problem, I think I was confused about what type of data I need. I get JSON but need a javascript obj. Turns out using eval on the data and accessing it like so "r[++j] = data[key]["planet"];" works.

Comment: To do one better, you were totally right: using dataType json (I swear the guy I got my code from did it the other way around! :D) is enough, you don't even need to "eval" the data afterwards.

Comment: @ChristianGeese Exactly, when you specify the data type as `json`, jQuery parses the result to get you a javascript object.